# Angular 2.rc-5 conflicting error messages

Tags: angular

I have quite a large app that I tried to port from rc-4 to rc-5 today. I remodeled everything to fit the new module architecture that seems to be promoted by the angular team. Somehow, I manage to have this written at the same time in the console. The first one is a warning, the second one is an error.

### Warning, ChildComponent is not declared

> NgModule AppModule uses ChildComponent via "entryComponents" but it was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an error after final.
>   core.umd.js:241 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

### Oh not wait, it's declared twice

> platform-browser.umd.js:946 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Type ChildComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ChildModule!

My theory is that somehow angular fixes the AppComponent not being declared itself, twice... Working to reproduce this somewhere that I can share.

Answer (score 0):

just put the name of your `ChildComponent` in declaration array in `NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    childComponent //your child component here
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AdminAuthGuard,
    UserAuthGuard
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I've tried that. I've tried every possible permutation of declarations across all my modules but it doesn't change anything. I have an idea though. I think I didn't correctly set up the routes.

Comment: @ashdeb have you found a solution to your problem? If so, could you please post it as an answer?  I am facing the same issue since 2 days...

Comment: Yes and no. Turn out I had another issue (that one : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10647#issuecomment-239437321) that I had to work around and when I was done I didn't have this problem anymore.